# Error displaying listview path information

Tags: flutter, dart

iOS novice coder learning flutter here. The goal of my app is to download pdfs from my firebase and display them offline in an image viewer. My code currently is able to download the pdf from the different nodes in my database and store them in a specific location. However, when I try and have the 'path category's' displayed as buttons to show the multiple PDFs, it says there is nothing in the path.

Am I missing something simple here, or am I doing my code incorrectly? Below is a picture of the terminal after downloading the pdfs, then displaying the listview: https://imgur.com/a/UdFlvsI

This code downloads the pdfs:

> 

```
  void fetchDataFromFirebase() {
>     _databaseReference.once().then((DatabaseEvent event) {
>       if (event.snapshot.value != null) {
>         final data = event.snapshot.value;
>         List<String> newAgencyNames = [];
> 
>         if (data is Map<dynamic, dynamic>) {
>           data.keys.forEach((dynamic agencyName) {
>             final agencyInfo = data[agencyName] as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
> 
>             if (agencyInfo != null && agencyInfo.containsKey("Protocols")) {
>               if (agencyName is String) {
>                 newAgencyNames.add(agencyName);
>               }
>             }
>           });
>         }
>         setState(() {
>           agencyNames = newAgencyNames;
>         });
>       }
>     }).catchError((error) {
>       print('Error fetching data: $error');
>     });
>   }
```

This code displays the listview:

```
 Future<void> fetchDataFromLocalDirectory() async {
    try {
      // Specify the directory path where you want to list subdirectories
      String directoryPath =
          '/data/user/0/com.mycompany.ncprotocols/app_flutter/Alamance';

      Directory directory = Directory(directoryPath);

      List<String> newSubfolderNames = [];

      // List subdirectories in the specified directory
      List<FileSystemEntity> entities = await directory.list().toList();

      for (var entity in entities) {
        if (entity is Directory) {
          // Get the name of the subdirectory
          String subfolderName = entity.uri.pathSegments.last;

          // Add the subdirectory name to the list
          newSubfolderNames.add(subfolderName);

          // Debug: Print subdirectory name
          print('Subdirectory Name: $subfolderName');
        }
      }

      setState(() {
        subfolderNames = newSubfolderNames;
      });
    } catch (error) {
      print('Error fetching local data: $error');
    }
  }
```